# How to run a function using a nhibernate criteria?

Tags: nhibernate, user-defined-functions, nhibernate-criteria

We have a search routine that uses criteria to build SQL query (because its restrictions added dynamically).
In a particular case (a very complicated case) we need to search over a table-valued function.(our model object is mapped to the function).

The result would be something like this :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.GetSubStaffsLetterInstances(@staffId) WHERE LetterNumber="1234";
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass @staffId to my criteria(I tried adding an Eq restrictions without success since restrictions are working on properties)
I know I can add a parameter to an IQuery but I don't know how I can do it using an ICriteria object.

Comment: `Projection.SqlFunction(...)` but i don't think it is supported in the from clause

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question completely, you can resort back to standard SQL:-

```
var sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.GetSubStaffsLetterInstances(:staffId) 
   WHERE LetterNumber=:letterNum";

var count = session.CreateSqlQuery(sql)
  .setInt32("staffId", 12345)
  .setString("letternum", "A1")
  .UniqueResult<int>();
```

or try `.UniqueResult<long>();` as I can't remember which one HQL returns

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.GetSubStaffsLetterInstances(:staffId) 
   WHERE LetterNumber=:letterNum is the production of a criteria and is produced dynamically.It can be different according to what a user wants to search.

Comment: Only HQL will allow you to work with table valued functions. Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249885/can-i-use-table-valued-function-as-query-source-in-nhibernate